# How to assign a color for a single surface without changing the other side color?

Tags: color, vertex-colors

[Blood vessel][1]

I am trying to draw a 3D blood vessel. I want the outer side of the vessel to be darker than the the inner layer. My problem is when I assign a color it will be applied for both inner and outer layer.

Is there any simple way to assign the color to the outer surface only just like the attached photo (red surface and yellow inner layer)?
Thank you!

[image: Blood vessel with red surface and yellow inner layer]

[1]: [image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create the thickness of the walls of your blood-vessel using a *Solidify* modifier, you can set material offsets for the generated faces:

Here's a tube generated from a simple Bezier Curve (right), using its native 'Bevel' setting, followed by a *Solidify* modifier to give the walls thickness, (and a *Bevel* **modifier** to sharpen the rim's edges):

[image]

- The top box shows the material slots for the curve
- The middle box shows its 'Material Offset' settings in its *Solidify* modifier
- The bottom box shows the 'Bevel' settings in the curve's *Data* tab >  *Geometry* panel

Comment: Actually I couldn't get the third box. I tried to add these two modifiers but the result was the bezier doubled and didn't turned into a tube!

Comment: @MajdiAl-Amili         It's unfortunate that a _Bevel_ modifier, and the curve's own 'Bevel' are called the same thing, when they are completely different. The 'Bevel' that turns the curve into a tube is in the curve's own _Data_ tab, _Geometry_  panel: https://imgur.com/a/HMa1Qdp

Comment: Done! That is very interesting. I used a cylinder because I can delete some faces to make some pores or a window to let some particle to be visible to the outside, but how to make a pore in this way of beveled bezier?

Comment: @MajdiAl-Amili  a _Boolean_ modifier could cut the windows to look inside procedurally. Convincing pores would be more work with procedural textures etc. Possible, but only worth setting up if you have to produce a wide variety of illustrations. You _can_ vary the thickness of the walls by vertex-weight, and the diameter of the vessel as a whole by the 'Radius' of the curve ( A different question).  Depending on how many of these you have to make, it may be just worth going as far as you can with thee modified curve for modelling, followed by conversion to a static mesh, for further detailing.

Comment: I was thinking the boolean modifier is easy for me. There was no such modifier in the formed tubed. I added an icosphere but it can't recognize the tube to apply difference option.
I really like this beveled bezier; therefore, I will try procedural texture. 
How to vary the thickness of the wall? i will try to upload the new file again.

Comment: I updated the .BLEND file if you would like to have a look.

Comment: Succeed! it converted to mesh and worked.
I would like to thank you so much and wish you happiness everyday. Thanks!

Comment: @MajdiAl-Amili Great! Peace and good health to you and yours, too.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this quite easy without the need of two different materials. Delete the second one, and edit the first material by adding a *Mix RGB* node in the *Shader Editor*. with the outside color on the first color and the inner color on the second. Then add a *Geometry* node and plug the *Backfacing* output in the *Fac* input of the *Mix RGB* node.

[image: color mix]

However, no blood vessel is infinitely thin, as you can see in you reference image there is a red tube with some thickness enclosing another lighter colored tube with thickness inside of that. So I would actually model two tubes, each with their own color so different colors for inside and outside would not be necessary.

Comment: That is very cool! But why when I add a solidify modifier the color will be back to single?

Comment: Yes, of course. I guess you should do basic tutorials on what faces are, what backfacing is, the modifiers... My setup works, because you have polygons where you can see the front/outside and the back/inside. If you solidify them, they are like e.g. a cube, they have a real outside enclosing a space between those polygons. Since it is closed, you cannot see the backfaces or inside of the polygons. As described in the other answer, when using a _Solidify Modifier_ you can specify extra materials for the newly created faces. But in your reference there are two tubes, each with his own color.

Comment: OK, can I make it more complicated and i just want to know if blender can make 10 colors on the surface and another different 10 colors in the back after we give up the solidify?

Comment: @MajdiAl-Amili Well, that depends on how you want to determine where which color should be, I'd say...